# Unity3D build error CommandInvokationFailure

Tags: build-error

When I try to build my project I get the following error

```
Error building Player: CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to recompile android resource files. See the Console for details.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_55\bin\javac.exe -bootclasspath "C:/Users/Ryan/Documents/android sdk only/android-sdk-windows/platforms/android-20\android.jar" -d "C:\Users\Ryan\Documents\Game - Android\Temp\StagingArea\bin\classes" -source 1.6 -target 1.6 -encoding UTF-8 "-S\R.java" "com\RyanVitter\Game\R.java"

stderr[
-S\R.java:8: error: <identifier> expected
package -S;
```

Does anybody know why this error is being thrown?

Answer (score 0):

My team had an error similar to this, while trying to integrate the facebook SDK.

It worked fine on the computer which was used to import the SDK, but once things were added to git and commited, all other computers could not build to android, and the above error was shown in the console.

This was because unity seems also change some files outside of the project folder once the SDK is imported( We imported it through the asset store).

The solution then was to also import the facebook SDK to all other PCs via the asset store, and then do a "git reset --hard", which seemed to set up the unity editor correctly.

After these steps the project could build again.